# SQL Server insert flow

Tags: sql, sql-server

As I understood reading some articles in internet, SQL Server has a buffer cache where it stores pages, and when insert statement is executed, the modified data is written only to that buffer in memory, not to the disk.

And when system checkpoint comes all dirty pages are flushed to disk.

Does this mean that when we execute insert statement and get a return value that everything was ok, the data might still not be written to disk and in theory if system crash occurs before checkpoint, the dirty pages wont be saved to disk although we received information that everything was ok and the transaction is commited?

Comment: Your understanding is an oversimplification of how the system works.  SQL Server is (generally) ACID compliant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Because you totally ignore the 2nd part of the mechanism - the LOG FILE. The Log file keeps all changed pages and is flushed to disc. In case of a crash, upon start, the server will replay the changes from the log file.

Comment: But log is not written to file immediately, it is written just before the page is written to disk, also on checkpoint.

Comment: Ah, read it all. Follow the links. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186259(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks man, I didn't see that link the first time, this line is key: Log records are written to disk when the transactions are committed. I understand now.

Comment: One question comes to my mind now. Does this mean that if we have 5000 inserts in one transaction, it will execute faster than if every insert was in its own transaction? Because in the first case, log will be written to transaction log file only once, and in second case log will be written to file 5000 times...

Comment: Usually yes Aleksa. But it is not that simple. It really depends on the volume of data, the table structure (indexes, triggers, patitioning, etc) and the database files configurations. What I mean is that it could be faster to insert all 5000 rows at once than one by one, but for 500.000 rows, it may be faster to insert them 5000 at a time, in 100 transactions. The best practice here would be finding the right number of row to insert at a time, watching out for log file growth constraints.